# Rails Paperclip - manage assets via utility class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have to manage user avatars via a utility class in my Rails app. The utility class is already implemented and I can not modify it.

Getting the avatar is done through a call like `ThatUtility.get_avatar(user_id)`, the same for update and delete. 
ThatUtility stores and retrieves files from another server via REST calls, and there must be no file storing on my local machine.

Is there a way to use Paperclip in my situation?

Comment: To clarify: Are you saying that you need to create a class that generates REST calls to another server to retrieve, store, and delete images?

Comment: It already exists and it's not allowed to change it.
The only solution I see is to create controller which will call this utility. But in this case Paperclip creates files locally to